# ASP.NET Core open Popup from DevExpress gridview

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, devexpress-mvc

I am trying to open a popup that I created as a partial view. But I am not getting my expected result - how can I do this?

Here's the example of my DevExpress gridview:

```
<div class="table_box">

 @(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Comet2.Data.OrderSearchData>()
            .ID("gridContainer")
            .ShowBorders(true)
            .ShowColumnLines(true)
            .ShowColumnHeaders(true)
            .ShowRowLines(true)
            .AllowColumnReordering(true)
            .AllowColumnResizing(true)
            .Sorting(s => s.Mode(GridSortingMode.Multiple))
            .RemoteOperations(true)
            .Scrolling(scrolling => scrolling.ColumnRenderingMode(GridColumnRenderingMode.Virtual))
            .Paging(paging => paging.PageSize(50))
            .Pager(pager =>
            {
                pager.Visible(true);
                pager.DisplayMode(GridPagerDisplayMode.Full);
                pager.ShowPageSizeSelector(true);
                pager.AllowedPageSizes(new JS("[25,50,100]"));
                pager.ShowInfo(true).Visible(true);
                pager.ShowNavigationButtons(true);
            })
            .FilterRow(filterRow => filterRow
            .Visible(true)
            .ApplyFilter(GridApplyFilterMode.Auto)
            )
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
            columns.AddFor(m => m.ORDERNUM)
                .Caption("Order #")
                .CellTemplate(@<text>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("EditOrder", "Orders")?OrderNum=<%= data.ORDERNUM %>" target="_blank"><%= data.ORDERNUM %></a>
                </text>
    );          columns.AddFor(m => m.REF)
               .Caption("Reference #").CssClass("Reference-column");                     
                   columns.AddFor(m => m.DROPOFF)
                .Caption("Delivery");
                   columns.AddFor(m => m.DCITY)
                .Caption("Delivery City").CssClass("Delivery-column");
                   columns.AddFor(m => m.DROPDATE)
                .Caption("Deliver Date").CssClass("Delivery-column");
                   columns.AddFor(m => m.SERVICE)
                 .Caption("Service");
                  @* Here I want to add a link button that will open POPUP  *@ 
            })    
            .Summary(s => s.TotalItems(items =>
            {
                items.AddFor(m => m.TotalRows)

                .SummaryType(SummaryType.Count);
            })
            )
            .Grouping(grouping => grouping.AutoExpandAll(true))
            .GroupPanel(groupPanel => groupPanel.Visible(true))
            .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().LoadAction("GetOrdersData"))
            .Height(500)
            
    .OnContentReady("onContentReady")
    )
```